# My swift code doesn't simulate

Tags: ios, swift

I get this error when simulate my Swift code in Xcode:

> "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subdued=0*0) "

in this function:

```
@IBAction func buttonTappeeed(theButton: UIButton) {
    var a = answerField.text
    answerField.text  = a! + (theButton.titleLabel?.text ?? "")
}
```

and in this line:

```
var a = answerField.text
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subdued=0*0) "

Comment: No, the error message. There should be a human readable message pointing out the problem.

Comment: @MohammadHosseinzadeh make sure your textField and your button are connected to their outlets. Also you could simplify your code as follow:  answerField.text! +=  theButton.titleLabel?.text ?? ""

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements - a `UIButton` and `UITextField`. Now you want the text field to get the value as a concatenation of its current value and the label of the button you tap.

Here is the code that works:

```
@IBOutlet weak var answerField: UITextField!

@IBAction func answerButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let a = answerField.text
    answerField.text = a! + (sender.titleLabel?.text ?? "")

}
```

Here you have an outlet for the text field and an action for the button where you get the text from the sender as a `UIButton` and concatenate it with the current value of the text field.

Don't forget to connect the button to its corresponding action and the text field to its respective outlet in the Interface Builder.

Here is the result of a working app:

[image: Button and text field]